# Kubernetes Openshift Client Authentication

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, fabric8

I am working with openshift 3.9 and try to list all Pods in my Namespace with fabirc8 Kubernetes-client ( https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client ).
I am using Java8 and the openshift client in version

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>openshift-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Inside the pod I am able to get a list of pod using bash

```
# using TLS connection with crt file defined
curl --cacert $CERT \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
   https://$ENDPOINT/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/pods
```

This means that my serviceaccount has the permission to list pods inside the namespace.

With java I was not able to authorize jet.

```
 try (OpenShiftClient client = new DefaultOpenShiftClient()) {
        System.out.println("Client opened is: " + client.getConfiguration().getOauthToken());
        client.pods().list().getItems().stream().forEach(
                p -> System.out.println("pod: " + p));
    }
```

Even if I explicitly specify the client with a builderConfig the error is as
followed:

> Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Unexpected response (401 Unauthorized), to the authorization request. Missing header:[Location]!
> at io.fabric8.openshift.client.internal.OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.authorize(OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.java:128)
> at io.fabric8.openshift.client.internal.OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.intercept(OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.java:63)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
> at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
> at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:129)
> at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

The problem seems to be this class:
https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/openshift-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/openshift/client/internal/OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.java

In line 132 the location of the token is not set, so the token can't be found.
I am not able to solve this problem by myself. Maybe I have to set the Header Authorization: Bearer by myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
try creating client this way 
    private OpenShiftClient buildClient(String namespace) {
        logger.info("OpenShiftClient buildClient:" + openshiftConfig);
        return new DefaultOpenShiftClient(new ConfigBuilder().withMasterUrl(clusterUrl))
                .withNamespace(namespace)
                .withTrustCerts(true)
                .withDisableHostnameVerification(true)
                .withUsername(openshiftConfig.getUsername()).withPassword( Password).withTrustCerts(true).build());
    }
```